# Div is invisible but responds to touch

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, uiwebview

I don't have that much exp with css. I am testing the html in my iphone. The problem is that sometimes the div is not visible but still it responds to touches. When I debug in Safari by connecting it to a mac machine, it shows the div in the inspector but it is hidden on the device.

When I test the same on my ipad, And in portrait if my div is invisible and if I change the orientation, it becomes visible. I don't understand the magic thats happening here. Need some expert guidance on this. I want to display the HTML DIV and also need to enable touch. Please help.

Here is the css which I am using:

```
#container {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  background-position: 0px -2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.25, 0.1, 1.0);
  background-color: yellow;
 -webkit-transform-origin-x: 0px;
  -webkit-transform-origin-y: 0px;

 -webkit-transition-duration: 0ms;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);

}
```

Comment: You are using a negative margin of -20px. Maybe thats the reason you cannot see your div

Comment: Is the problem that you want the div to be visible but it's not, or that you don't want it to respond to clicks but it does? We need to know what you want to do before we can give a good answer for you.

Comment: But the div's height is dynamic and extends about the height of the device. Eventhough the margin is -20px. Obviously, It should fit within the size of the device. Anyways, I shall give it a try and update you

Comment: @DiMono, I want the div to be show and respond to touches. It is getting hidden somehow

Comment: @MarsOne, I removed the negative margin. Still having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using CSS `pointer-events`

Try setting

```
div
{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question. I need to make the div visible and also respond for touches.

Answer (score 0):

For different view ports (different screen widths), prefer using css through [Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/), it's the preferred method these days.